# Update fields of the principal at the runtime

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

I use OAuth2 authentication with my own authorization and resource server in Spring Boot. I want to change some fields in my `User implements UserDetails`(it's my `Principal`) object at runtime on behalf of the same user or on behalf of another user(administrator/moderator). E.g. `user1` with id=1 want to change his country, so he calls this method:

```
@PostMapping("/setMyCountry")
public void setMyCountry(@CurrentUser User user, @RequestParam String newCountry){
    user.setCountry(newCountry);
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

But when I want to check his country using this:

```
@GetMapping("/getMyCountry")
public String getMyCountry(@CurrentUser User user){
    return user.getCountry();
}
```

I get the same old country.

Similarly, with the changes as administrator:

```
@PostMapping("/setUserCountry")
public void setUserCountry(@CurrentUser Moderator moderator, @RequestParam String newCountry){
    User user = userRepository.findById(1L).get();
    user.setCountry(newCountry);
    userRepository.save(user);
}

@GetMapping("/getUserCountry")
public String getUserCountry(@CurrentUser Moderator moderator){
    User user = userRepository.findById(1L).get();
    return user.getCountry();
}
```

It returns the same country. But, of course, the DB shows new value.

I already saw question about the similar issues, but if I use this in `setMyCountry()`:

```
Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
```

then this still doesn't work. Please note, that I use my custom tokens, token providers and token granters, but they all return `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` at the end.

So, how can I change field of the `User` and update current principal without log out and log in?

Comment: The user principal should not be the User object. Common practice is that the UserDetails object contains authorization details about the user. What roles and such, not personal information as firstname, lastname address and country and such. Thats what the user object from the database is for. The UserPrincipal may contain a userId to make a DB lookup of the user

Comment: @ThomasAndolf thanks, can you please share a link with an example of what you are talking about? I want to see implementation details.

Comment: Implementation details? You have an id in your jwt, this then gets converted into your custom userdetails object. This id is an id you can use to lookup the userId object in the database.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I ask because it is not absolutely clear to me what you mean. Are you mean that I need two tables in my DB: with my custom `UserDetails`(username, password) and `UserInformation`/`User`(aboutMe, country etc.)? Or I can save my current DB scheme, so I need only `User` table(with id, username, password, but also with all other information, e.g. aboutMe, country, etc.), but  two classes in the Spring: `CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails` and `User` entity? Please add more details from this point of view.

Comment: what kind of login flow are you doing? Session? Oauth2? jwt?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf as I said, it's OAuth2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common practice when using oauth2 is that the Authentication server knows nothing about the users, more than user name, password, what roles, and an some sort of key so it can look up the user object. This can be a unique UUID, or the username (subject) as in an email address.

The resource server gets a token from a client, it takes this token and then calls the authorization server to verify the token, the authorization server verifies it and if verified then sends back information to the resource server so that the resource server can populate its UserDetails object.

If the resource server needs to know say what country this user lives in, it gets the id from the Principal/UserDetails object and then calls maybe a user service, or another database, or another table, or even back to the authorization server that maybe has a /user endpoint and presents the token to the authorization server (that in turn gets the principal info, gets the subject and then looks up in a database for the user info) and then send the user object back.

What my point is that you should always separate Authentication and Authorization (roles etc) information, from the actual User information.

What if you change from say using facebook authentication to github authentication. Do you need to redo all the users? no, because you have all user information separated from the authorization information.

Comment: Thanks! But if I use my own authorization and resource server, then is it ok to use only one `Users` table, but two classes in the Spring: `CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails` and `User` entity?

Comment: as i said and i have pointed out many, many, many times. It is bad practice, even though you own both or not. Just because you can, doesn't mean it is good.